# How to validate a date using Python pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My data frame consists of a column of dates, which are not necessarily in the correct format. for example: **13/13/2020** or **13/10/2011** - if the format is `mm/dd/yyyy.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use the [built in functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for something like this:

```py
pd.to_datetime(Q4_df['issdt'], infer_datetime_format=True, errors='coerce')
```

Tune the `errors` param to get the behavior you want:

```
errors{‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}, default ‘raise’
   If ‘raise’, then invalid parsing will raise an exception.
   If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaT.
   If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input.
```